# How to do comment and document on Window Workflow Foundation

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

I am working with few simple xoml workflow (.NET 3.5), and I want to add few simple comment and note on the xoml file.

I can find a "Description" property on activity, but that not easy to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find anything like that.

I guess workflows are supposed to be self explanatory so comments are considered obsolete. Lack of Description property you mentioned in WWF4 seems to prove this.

So in WWF3 you can use Description property. It is unformatted text, but retains line endings. And it's shown when you hover mouse pointer above activity in designer.

In WWF4 the only way is adding XML comments in .xaml files.

And always you can create some kind of Comment activity yourself. It could have rich-text Description property which would be shown in its editor control within workflow designer. The major drawback of this solution is some additional runtime cost when executing this activity.

Answer (score 0):

Don't the classical xml style comment apply to xoml files ?

```
<!-- comment -->
```

Comment: To be fair, no body will even watch on the xoml file source. I wonder if the GUI editor is guarantee to keep your comments?